# Haskell Map and Filter

Tags: function, haskell, dictionary, filter

Here is my issue: I have two lists as follows: `[(Float, Integer)]` and `[(String, Integer)]`. Now I need to define a function that takes these two Lists and two `Float` values and returns a list of `Strings`. The two Float values correspond to a range given (min and max). I have to filter the first list so it only contains elements that are within the min and max range. Then, I need to use the filtered list and take it's `Integer` values, match them with the `Integer` values in the second list and return all the `String` values that match.

I have already defined a function for use as a filter condition that takes a `(Float,Integer)` and checks the `Float` value to see if it is within the given range.

And I have defined a function to take a `(String,Integer)` element and return the `String`.

I'm just having problems linking everything together, or maybe I am missing something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need (for example, there are different ways)

```
integersFromRange :: Float -> Float -> [(Float,Integer)] -> [Integer]
stringsFromInteger :: Integer -> [(String,Integer)] -> [String]
```

`integersFromRange` is basically `map snd . filter condition`, with `condition` constructed from the two `Float`s (you have that). `stringsFromInteger` could be implemented as `map fst . filter condition`. Then you combine the functions with

```
result = concatMap (`stringsFromInteger` stringList) (integerFromRange mini maxi floatList)
```

Using a set of `Integer`s instead of a list would be more efficient since membership test in a `Set` is faster than in a list.

Comment: Ah I think I've found a mistake I've made... my filter condition takes a single element, i.e. (Float,Integer) so when I'm trying to pass it the list [(Float,Integer)] I am getting errors. This is what it looks like: check :: (Float,Integer) ->  Float -> Float -> Bool
check b min max = if ((fst b) >= min && (fst b) <= max)
 then True
 else False

Comment: Hmm though I'm not sure how to overcome this as the filter condition shouldn't take a list, it should just check single elements?

Comment: Change the order of arguments, `check2 :: Float -> Float -> (Float,integer) -> Bool`, then filter with `filter (check2 mini maxi)`. Partial application FTW.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Well I have the integersFromRange working although I'm a little confused about the stringsFromInteger - when you say filter condition you mean a different filter condition right?

Comment: Yes, I used the name `condition` generically, which condition to use where depends on the task and types.

Comment: Oh of course you do, I've defined my own function and it's working now. Although my final result function doesn't work - for the result function are the 's necessary?

Comment: `result` isn't a function, just a list of `String`s. If I understand your question correctly, those are not apostrophes but backticks, which can be used to apply a function infix, like `3 \`elem\` [1 .. 10]` instead of `elem 3 [1 .. 10]`. So they are necessary because it's the second argument of `stringsFromInteger` that's given, not the first (but you could also use `flip` as in `flip stringsFromInteger stringList`).

Comment: Ah I see, well I have defined it as a function and it works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!